# How can I return None from a function that borrows from it's argument, or avoid needing to?

Tags: rust

I have a slice of Option, and given a value, if that value is a valid index in the slice I want to use the value at that index, otherwise use `None`.

Now, values need to be able to be reused, so I think I want to borrow from my slice, not move... Note that `Foo` does not implement the `Copy` trait and I'd prefer to keep it that way.

I need to do this often, so a function returning `&Option<Foo>` seemed appropriate, with the addition of a lifetime specifier since obviously the return value shouldn't outlive the slice it is borrowed from. That leads me to:

```rust
fn get_or_none<'a>(data: &'a [Option<Foo>], bar: u8) -> &'a Option<Foo> {
  match bar as usize {
    idx if idx < data.len() => &data[idx],
    _ => &None // obviously can't work
  }
}
```

This is clearly wrong. I can cheat, for now, because I know for this particular application the first value in the slice will always be None (it's a property of my data, so to speak), but that's just avoiding the problem.

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few approaches you could take:

1. Add another layer of `Option`ness, returning a `Option<&Option<Foo>>`. I’m guessing you don’t want to do this.
2. Return an `Option<&Foo>` instead of `&Option<Foo>`:

   ```rust
   fn get_or_none(data: &[Option<Foo>], bar: u8) -> Option<&Foo> {
       match data.get(bar as usize) {
           Some(&Some(ref foo)) => Some(foo),
           _ => None,
       }
   }
   ```
3. Store a suitable `None` as a static and return a reference to it. Its lifetime is `'static` (so long as `Foo` is `'static`), so a reference to it can be shortened to `'a` with no problems.

   ```rust
   static NO_FOO: Option<Foo> = None;

   fn get_or_none(data: &[Option<Foo>], bar: u8) -> &Option<Foo> {
       data.get(bar as usize).unwrap_or(&NO_FOO)
   }
   ```

Comment: 1. looks like cruft. 3 sounds like an antipattern. 2. looks good - is your choice of destructuring `data.get()` with nested `Some`s considered more idiomatic? I find checking the length easier to understand but that is probably because I'm new to Rust.

Comment: Depending on the semantic meaning of your `Option<Foo>`, any of the three could easily be the most suitable (OK, three less so), though I would tend to expect the second to be the best one. It, by the way, could be written `data.get(bar as usize).and_then(|x| x.as_ref())`. I just go with what feels the nicest, and in the second case I felt that a more complex pattern was better and clearer than `and_then` plus `as_ref`, while in the third I felt that `unwrap_or` was a good choice. It’s all fairly subjective, I’m afraid.

Comment: Thanks to you I have just discovered `and_then()` and `or_else()`. Very handy. I agree in this case it's less obvious what is going on with `and_then` than with a match clause, but as you say, it's subjective.

Answer (score 4):

As you don't apparently need to mutate the slice through this function, an alternative would be to switch your return type from `&'a Option<Foo>` to `Option<&'a Foo>`. This way, you won't have any problem with returning `None`.

To do this, you can use the [`Option::as_ref(..)`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) method, which allows you to turn a `&Option<Foo>` into a `Option<&Foo>`.

In the end, you have:

```rust
fn get_or_none<'a>(data: &'a [Option<Foo>], bar: u8) -> Option<&'a Foo> {
    match bar as usize {
        idx if idx < data.len() => data[idx].as_ref(),
        _ => None
    }
}
```